# How do I configure asciidoctor-gradle-plugin to handle plantuml?

Tags: ruby, gradle, plantuml, asciidoctor

I don't know any Ruby but I do like `asciidoctor` (and the gradle plugin).  Is there a simple way to get the plugin to generate [plantuml](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/) diagrams?

I looked at the basic [asciidoctor-diagrams](http://asciidoctor.org/news/2014/02/18/plain-text-diagrams-in-asciidoctor/) functionality which seems specific to using the native/ruby asciidoctor extension (which I don't have and would rather not install since I like using the gradle plugin).

The nicely done [asciidoctor-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin) documentation page shows that it accepts a `requires` option for Ruby modules but having no grounding in Ruby whatsoever, I'm not sure if that's what I need or not.

I tried the path of least resistant, i.e.:

```
asciidoctor {
    logDocuments = true
    separateOutputDirs = false
    sourceDir = file("src")
    outputDir = file("$buildDir/html")
    backends = [ 'html5' ]
    requires "asciidoctor-diagram"
}
```

Against my basic plantuml test:

```
.The PlantUML block extension class
[plantuml, sample-plantuml-diagram, alt="Class diagram", width=135, height=118]
----
class BlockProcessor
class PlantUmlBlock
BlockProcessor <|-- PlantUmlBlock
----
```

But got:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':asciidoctor'.
> (LoadError) no such file to load -- asciidoctor-diagram
```

during the configuration phase.

How can I configure `asciidoctor-gradle-plugin` to handle plantuml?

Comment: Which version ate you using?

Comment: I'm using: asciidoctor-gradle-plugin v1.5.1, and I have asciidoctorj at 1.5.2 (mmm, should I keep those in sync?).

Comment: It's best if they are. I believe there's also a jar now for asciidoctor-diagram.

Comment: At least looking for asciidoctor-diagram jar led me to mrhaki, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[mrhaki to the rescue.](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/11/awesome-asciidoctor-use-asciidoctor.html)  I don't want to totally rip-off his post, but in case that link ever goes bad, there are numerous other dependencies that need to be met in the gradle file the first that I didn't have was `com.github.jruby-gradle:jruby-gradle-plugin:0.1.5` then he applies two plugins including `com.github.jruby-gradle.base` and has a dependency on ruby gems (`rubygems:asciidoctor-diagram:1.2.0`).  I think his blog site is pretty reliable so I won't go into the details.

Comment: FYI. . . I thought since mrhaki had laid it all out I'd be fine, but apparently I jumped the gun since I am still getting the loadfile error.  Seems I lost the battle on this one.

Comment: Through time `asciidoctor-gradle-plugin` got a nice example repository https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-gradle-examples/ which might be helpful for anybody popping in here

Comment: the Link to mrHaki helped me, to get it working. I had to add `:imagesdir: images` to my asciidoc document.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the source was that I was missing the line

```
gemPath = jrubyPrepare.outputDir
```

which seems to communicate the path where gems are stored to the asciidoctor task

Or at least this makes the `no such file to load` problem go away, I then got an error about not finding graphviz, which I could fix by installing graphviz on my machine.